# If and else if in sharepoint list calculated column giving syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column-formula, calculated-column, if-condition

I have two date fields **date1**, **date2** and stores in column name **result** . I need the difference of the two dates to be calculated and store no of days in the **result**.

Problem here is with two cases:

1. case 1: if **date1** is lesser than **date2** then Null error.
2. case 2: if **date2** is lesser than **date1** then Null error.

Condition I placed is:

```
IF(OR(ISBLANK([Date1]),ISBLANK([Date2])),"",IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([Date1][Date2])),"DATEDIF([Date2],[Date1],"D")",IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([Date2][Date1])),"DATEDIF([Date1],[Date2],"D")")))
```

I am pretty confused in figuring out the trick. Help me in getting this.

Comment: In below comments you mentioned, you want to calculate based on Today's date. Do you want to calculate this everyday when (Today) changes? or only when saving the item?

Comment: only while saving.

Comment: If your Date1 > Today, then what do you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your formula (extra `"` and commas are missing at some places).

Try using below formula:

```
IF(OR(ISBLANK([Date1]),ISBLANK([Date2])),"",IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([Date1],[Date2],"D")),DATEDIF([Date2],[Date1],"D"),IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([Date2],[Date1],"D")),DATEDIF([Date1],[Date2],"D"),"")))
```

Comment: Still same error Ganesh.

Comment: Actually the date1 column contains todays date and date2 contains <todays-date>(less than or greater than todays date). I need to get the difference of those tow columns. to get todays date(date1) I have followed https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-get-the-current-date-in-sharepoint-calculated-column/ 
this blog, and date2 column user enters some random date. result should come as the difference b/w days. if you have any other idea please suggest me.

Comment: Try using this simple formula: `IF(OR(ISBLANK([Date1]),ISBLANK([Date2])),"",DATEDIF([Date1],[Date2],"D"))`

Comment: Tried this, but DATEDIF([Date1],[Date2]) is giving a negative number also(if date1 is bigger than date2). thats why I have been trying for other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing today's date in a column. You can use `**TODAY()**` in your calculated column which returns today's date. Try the formula below if it helps.

```
IF(ISBLANK([Date2]),"",IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(Today(),[Date2],"D")), DATEDIF([Date2],Today(),"D"), DATEDIF(Today(),[Date2],"D")))
```

Comment: Today() is giving an error, trying to use a column which doesn't exist.